# How to return 404 on wrong API url? (ASP.NET Core + SPA)

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to return 404 on wrong api call so I can create proper response to user on client side (Angular 5). Currently backend returns status code 200 and index.html, and that results in json parse error on frontend.

I created new web project with ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Angular template project.  Here's [the link](https://wrongapiurltestapp.azurewebsites.net/) to published version of that template. I didn't change template code at all, I just published that on azure as it is. (In dev mode I get 404 error as expected).

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/973#issuecomment-303778580) default behaviour should be 404.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Wme9MKUR) is the `Startup.cs`, and [here](https://pastebin.com/wtGXkH9Z) `SampleDataController.cs`.

I thought of using something like this in `Startup.cs`:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });

        app.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/api"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Error" });
            });
        });
```

And in `HomeController.cs`:

```
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
```

But that seems wrong although it works.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I am still using the described "solution".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Note:** Based on your links, I assume you are using the `app.UseSpa()` middleware.

The route middleware is executed in order, and if the  request never finds a controller a `404` status is returned. The `UseSpa` middlware is a catch-all, and any request that gets to that point will always have the default SPA page returned. This means any request to a route that hasn't yet found a controller will always return the default SPA page, and not throw a 404.

What you will want to do is only call `UseSpa()` if the route is not prefixed with `/api`. Which essentially lets any requests that start with`/api` skip past that point.

**Instead of:**

```cs
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    //[Snip]
});
```

**Use:**

```cs
app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
{
    builder.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        //[Snip]
    });
});
```

This will let any request that starts with `/api` past that point, and if no other middleware or routes are matched, a `404` will be returned.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Douglas for his excellent answer.  I improved upon it:

```
app.UseWhen( c => !c.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments( new PathString( "/api" ) ), app =>
    app.UseSpa( spa => {
        //[Snip]
    } ) );
```